# Rails 4 render js: redirecting to another page and displaying raw js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my `TestimoniesController` I have written a `render js:` line in the event that `@testimony.save` is not successful.

```
if @testimony.save  
  redirect_to @testimony
else 
  render js: "alert('Please make sure you feel out every field of the Testimonial!');"
end
```

Instead of rendering the alert that I write, it redirects me to the `/testimonies` route and just displays the string that was supposed to be rendered as javascript and nothing else. Is my JS disabled somehow?

Here is my `new.html.erb` file:

```
<h1> New Testimonial</h1> 
<%= form_for :testimony, url:testimonies_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :contact_number %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :contact_number %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :country %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :country %>
  </p>
  <p>

  <!--bunch of the same stuff -->
  <p>
  <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you add `remote: :true` in your link which hits to this controller action

Comment: SHare your html file as well

Comment: I think you should use the js.erb file for methods and show the response to user.

Comment: @Abk where would I put remote: :true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order tor respond with js, you have to add remote: :true in your form_for, and submit your request as ajax

```
<%= form_for :testimony, url:testimonies_path, remote: :true do |f| %>
```

but then your

```
 redirect_to @testimony
```

will not work as it only works on html format, so in that scenario replace this line with

```
render js "location.href = '#{testimony_path}'";
```